# How to check solaris LDOM build?

Tags: solaris

I have a newly built Solaris LDOM, I need to check the same for acceptance. Can anybody tell me which commands I need to perform to check whether the LDOM is properly built?

Comment: You should take a moment to review the questions you've asked to see if any of the answers worked for you.  Only you've only marked accepted answers on 2 of your questions so far.  It's good feedback to the community to know when an answer solves the problem.

Comment: yes will it do shortly..

Comment: Hi, Any response to the above question?

Answer (score 0):

Properly built for what? You need to define what you want your LDOM to be ready to serve. An LDOM build is no different from a normal Solaris installation.
The only things to check that are LDOM specific are possibly hardware resources available to the LDOM, has the SA assigned the correct number of threads/cores to the LDOM, correct amount of memory and disk etc. The commands to check this are the same as you use to check in non-LDOM Solaris (psrinfo, prtdiag etc).